# Multi-node SLURM pure python solution

Tags: python, nodes, slurm

I am working on a project to execute a multi-noded python script on a SLURM cluster. The solution should be p2p. The problem is that I don't really have an idea where to start. Though, I should broadcast first right? Finding out which nodes are assigned to my job (4 nodes), and then, utilize every node with 1/4 part of the job(?). Every node must keep track of which part of the job has been done, right? I heard someone mention a file-based solution, but I didn't quite understand that. Hope you guys can help me with this. ALso, no MPI or anything like that, should be used.

(the job I should submit, is reading in a large file, and processing every line of that file)

Answer (score 0):

You say the overall task is to read a large file and process every line.

First, you need a strategy to divide the work.  Having a single process read the entire file and then send it to the rest might make sense if your disk is very slow and your network is very fast, but more likely you want to divide the reading task.

You can often do these things without explicit communication between the processes.  Just have the first process read the first 25% of the file's bytes, then continue reading until it sees one more newline.  The second process reads 25% to 50% within the file, then continues until it sees one more newline.  And so on.

This way, all you need to do is tell the processes three facts on startup:

1. The file path.
2. The number of processes (N) which will process the file.
3. The index of each specific process (0 to N), so that it can infer which portion to read.

Comment: Indeed. But I already have the things you named in your list. The problem is that SLURM randomly assigns 4 nodes to my job. Now, I have to figure out, inside python somehow, which nodes have been assigned to my job, and then, run the master script to give every node its part of the job. Then, the client scripts will each do 20% of the job. So how do I retrieve the node list, into python?

Comment: @ReneBults: Launch a single SLURM "array job" which has 4 tasks.  Then read `os.environ['SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID']` from Python to know which task it is.